# What should I do if I get this warning in QGIS during uploading changes in a project?

Tags: qgis, qfield

The layer is not configured with neither cable, nor cloud action yet. Default action will be selected only for this time. Please select and save appropriate layer action in "Layer Properties -> QField".

I have no clue what I am supposed to do, does someone know the solution?
The Project is already in the cloud, but I added a few layers and for them popps the warning up.

Answer (score 0):

Open the layer's properties and set the cloud action on the QField tab.

Comment: There is "Offline edeting" selected, like in the other layers which are working

Comment: I still don't have a clue what to do